# C enum typedef in Python ctypes TypeError

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am trying to call an external C library in Python using ctypes.  I was making good progress until I got to a specific function call which was referencing a certain enum, which defined in the header file as something like this:

```
typedef enum { a = 0,
               b
             } A;
```

I've tried various ways of calling the function, but I keep getting:

```
a = libc.function2(out, 0, outputCallback, c_int(1), 1)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 3
```

Here is my code with the function names changed to generic, the problem is in the second function call:

```
cdll.LoadLibrary("library.so")

libc = CDLL("library.so")


def outputCallback():
    print "Hello"

// This function executes properly
out = libc.function1(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)


// Function that gives error                  #
a = libc.function2(out, 0, outputCallback, c_int(1), 1)
```

Comment: I think I see the problem, and understand you question.  Arguments aren't numbered from 0, they are numbered from 1.  The problem is with my callback function.